# Customize QTreeWidgetItem Pyside2

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` where I want each row to be like this widget:

[image]

I know how to create the widget itself, how to create a basic QTreeWidgetItem but I don't know how to tie the both of them together.

I am using PySide2 and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any Minimal Reproducible Example and If I andertood your question you can try something like that.

It create an item and in each column you can assign a text or another widget.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.treewidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.treewidget.setColumnCount(4)

        layout.addWidget(self.treewidget)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.build_tree()


    def build_tree(self):
        for index in range(10):
            item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treewidget)
            item.setText(0, 'icon 1')
            item.setText(1, 'icon 2')

            line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.treewidget)

            push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.treewidget)
            push_button.setText('TEST')

            self.treewidget.setItemWidget(item, 2, line_edit)
            self.treewidget.setItemWidget(item, 3, push_button)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

And if you don't want to have more than one column in your treewidget, I think you can use a Qwidget and a layout like this (just replace the method).

```
def build_tree(self):
   for index in range(10):
   item = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treewidget)

   widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
   layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

   label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('icon 1')
   label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('icon 2')
   line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
   push_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('TEST')

   layout.addWidget(label_1)
   layout.addWidget(label_2)
   layout.addWidget(line_edit)
   layout.addWidget(push_button)

   widget.setLayout(layout)

   self.treewidget.setItemWidget(item, 0, widget)
```

and remove this line in the init method:

```
self.treewidget.setColumnCount(4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. You saved my day sir! :)